# Why more than 1 drop downs are not working in Materializecss?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, materialize

I have multiple drop down menus on the single page. I am using Materializecss.com. The Error is, I am getting values of the first drop down in every dropdown menu in the whole page. Here is the code.

```
@if($user->is_banned != 1)
    <a class='dropdown-button btn-flat' href='#' data-constrainWidth="false" data-activates='dropdownUser'><i class="material-icons left">expand_more</i> More</a>
    <ul id="dropdownUser" class="dropdown-content">
        <li><a href="/user/ban/{{ $user->id }}" target="_blank"><i class="material-icons left">insert_chart</i>BAN</a></li>
        <li><a href="#deleteUserModal" data-userId="{{ $user->id }}" class="deleteUser red-text"><i class="material-icons left">delete</i>Delete</a></li>
    </ul>
@else
```

The Problem is, For example, If I have the list of 5 users on the same page, I am getting values of the first user in all the dropdown menus. I don't know what's wrong.

I tried to change class to ID but not working. I am a bit new to `Jquery`.

**UPDATE:** Okay, I found the error. Here is the new code that works! Thanks for Help StackOverflow!

```
@if($user->is_banned != 1)
    <a class='dropdown-button btn-flat' href='#' data-constrainWidth="false" data-activates='dropdownUser-{{ $user->id }}'><i class="material-icons left">expand_more</i> More</a>
    <ul id="dropdownUser-{{ $user->id }}" class="dropdown-content">
        <li><a href="/user/ban/{{ $user->id }}" target="_blank"><i class="material-icons left">insert_chart</i>BAN</a></li>
        <li><a href="#deleteUserModal" data-userId="{{ $user->id }}" class="deleteUser red-text"><i class="material-icons left">delete</i>Delete</a></li>
    </ul>
@else
```

I Updated the working code instead of deleting the question because there might be many developers looking for the same solution!

Answer (score 0):

I have faced same issue working with materialize css.

I used

$('#tag_id').material_select();

while document is getting ready.